# Target table length not updated even when the source column length is updated

Tags: mapping, informatica

I had to change some of the column lengths in the source to a higher value in information, but I am still getting the same length as below and it looks like it was not updated. source and target are both oracle tables. Do I need to reimport source tables in information after changing column names?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to propagate the change across your mapping. Just right click on the attribute and select Propagate Attributes

Comment: I tried that but still, I am not getting the complete length of a column. The data is getting cut

Comment: Does every instance of the attribute in every component in the mapping have the correct length?  Do the actual source and target tables show the correct column length?

Comment: I just changed one column length from 7 to 15 and the other from 16 to 30 (both string). I first changed the source and then made the changes in the mapping as well. I refreshed the tables as well

Comment: The problem is even after changing, it is not getting reflected in the target data

Comment: Ok, thats not really something anyone can help with. You need to turn on debugging and look at the logs to see where the data is being truncated

Comment: I know you guys already discussed, but if your source or target definition changed, you need to either reimport or manually change length. And if you change both source and target definition, then propagate the length from source to target.